# Dynamic Pivot query with multiple table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join three table and get the desired result as show in image but I am unable to do. how can I solve this problem.
thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What steps have you taken to try to solve this problem? Also, take a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Images aren't a good way to supply data, we can't interact with it, making it all but useless to the people you are asking for help from. Formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements are a far better option. There are many duplicate questions on how to perform a dynamic pivot on Stack Overflow though what were wrong with those?

Comment: Take a look at this post regarding SQL PIVOT: : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Sample schema with data as below

```
CREATE Table tab1
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
[DATE] DATE,
Userid INT
) 
GO
CREATE Table tab2
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
StoreName varchar(20)
) 
GO
CREATE Table tab3
(
tab3ID INT IDENTITY,
OpenTime varchar(10),
CLoseTime varchar(10),
Table1_fk INT,
Table2_fk INT
) 
GO
ALTER Table tab1 ADD CONSTRAINT Pk_Table1 PRIMARY KEY (Id)
ALTER Table tab2 ADD CONSTRAINT Pk_Table2 PRIMARY KEY (Id)
ALTER Table tab3 ADD CONSTRAINT Fk_tab3Table2 FOREIGN  KEY (Table1_fk) REFERENCES tab1 (Id)
ALTER Table tab3 ADD CONSTRAINT Fk_tab3Table1 FOREIGN  KEY (Table2_fk) REFERENCES tab2 (Id)
GO

INSERT INTO tab1
SELECT '01-02-2019',20 UNION ALL
SELECT '01-02-2019',20 UNION ALL
SELECT '03-25-2019',20 UNION ALL
SELECT '03-25-2019',20
GO

INSERT INTO tab2
SELECT 'ShoesShop' UNION ALL
SELECT 'CoputerSalesShop' 
GO

INSERT INTO tab3
SELECT '10:00 Am','05:00 Pm',1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT '09:00 Am','04:00 Pm',2,2 UNION ALL
SELECT '10:00 Am','05:00 Pm',3,1 UNION ALL
SELECT '10:00 Am','04:00 Pm',4,2
```

i written some code which almost near to your requirement by using dynamic sql.I guess it will help you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempTable

SELECT ID,
       StoreName,
       [Times],
       [TimeData] ,
       Dates INTO TempTable
FROM 
(
SELECT StoreName,
        OpenTime,
        CLoseTime,
        [DATE] AS Dates,
        t1.ID
FROM tab3 t3
INNER JOIN tab2 t2
    ON t2.ID = t3.Table2_fk
INNER JOIN tab1 t1
    ON t1.ID = t3.Table1_fk
)AS A
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (OpenTime,'OpenTime'),
                     (CLoseTime,'CLoseTime')

            )AS dt([Times],[TimeData] )

SELECT * FROM TempTable

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
        @DynamicColumn nvarchar(max),
        @MaxDynamicColumn nvarchar(max)

SELECT @DynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+QUOTENAME(CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM TempTable  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SELECT @MaxDynamicColumn = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT', '+'MAX('+QUOTENAME(CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10)))+') AS '+QUOTENAME(CAST(Dates AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM TempTable  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 

SET @Sql='SELECT  StoreName,'+ @MaxDynamicColumn+'
            FROM
            (
            SELECT *,STUFF((SELECT '' AND ''+ [TimeData] +'' : ''+ [Times] 
                      FROM  TempTable i WHERE i.id = o.id FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,4,'''') AS ShopDateTIme
            FROM TempTable o
            )AS src
            PIVOT 
            (
            MAX(ShopDateTIme) FOR [Dates] IN ('+@DynamicColumn+')
            ) AS Pvt
            GROUP BY StoreName '
EXEC (@Sql)
PRINT @Sql
```